# SUM of all rows from WHERE condition?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add the contents of all the rows retrieved from a query.

So far I have tried:

```
$totalquery = "SELECT SUM(catalogue.price) AS fCount
        FROM catalogue LEFT JOIN orders ON catalogue.plantid = orders.orderplantid
        WHERE orders.orderplantid = '$actualresult' AND orders.ordercustomerid = '$actualresult2' GROUP BY catalogue.price";
        $result3 = mysql_query($totalquery) or die ("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
        $totalresult = mysql_result($result3,0);
```

and then echoing out the $totalresult, but the problem is only displays the last value, rather than the sum of all of the values selected - any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: If you remove the `sum` statement, does it give all the correct rows? Given that nothing is working, I would assume that your where statement is not working correctly, and that you're not selecting the rows you want to be selecting.

Comment: exactly the same thing happens - still outputs just the last price.

Comment: In that case, your `where` statements are too restrictive. Work on fixing those and the sum statement should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `GROUP BY catalogue.price` from the end of the line; the sum command IS one of the [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

Comment: Have done this but still with the same result of only the last item being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If the grouping results in multiple groups being formed, you'd need to retrieve the rows in a loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
    $total = $row['fCount'];
    ... do something with total ...
}
```

As it stands now, you're only fetching the first summed value and throwing away the rest.

Comment: I tried this and removed order by (just changed the var names) so my code is: while($rowtest = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
    $totaltest = $rowtest['fCount'];
    echo $totaltest;
}
  but it isn't outputting anything?

Comment: it returns the last row as it is at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

most likely because there are multiple results instead of just one.  and because you're not looping through the array and storing all values to view, all you're seeing is the last value of the result-set because it's the last assignment ot the $totalresult variable...

try mysql_fetch_assoc($result3) or mysql_fetch_array($result3) and loop through the results to get all returned information...

Comment: Tried this as Mark B suggested but with no luck, any ideas as to why?

Comment: try this: `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) { foreach ($row as $key => $val) { echo "$key: $val <br />";} 
}`

Answer (score 0):

instead of `mysql_result()` use `mysql_fetch_array()`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `GROUP BY` statement.

Also, if `$actualresult` and `$actualresult2` is input from the user, be sure to escape these to avoid SQL injection attacks:

```
$totalquery= "... WHERE orders.orderplantid = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($actualresult) . "' AND orders.ordercustomerid = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($actualresult2) . "'";
```